# PE Format: Why the IAT can be empty, and a MS detours myth

Tags: portable-executable, dll-injection, detours

To my knowledge the [import address table (IAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Import_Table) is a table of
import functions. But lately I found that in some executables the
IAT is empty: in IAT's directory, both VirtualAddress and Size are
zero. To my surprise, An executable without IAT could run.

Then I found some code in [MS detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/):

```
// If the file doesn't have an IAT_DIRECTORY, we create it...
if (inh.IAT_DIRECTORY.VirtualAddress == 0) {
    inh.IAT_DIRECTORY.VirtualAddress = obBase;
    inh.IAT_DIRECTORY.Size = cbNew;
}
```

There is an API called DetourCreateProcessWithDllExA in MS
detours, as its name said, it could launch an executable with
specified DLLs - it will create a process in suspended mode,
modify the import table (add DLLs), and resume the main thread to
run. The code above is a part of this procedure.

Depending on my test, if you comment the code above, process will
crash at very beginning. But even more amazing is that you could
modify the VirtualAddress and Size freely, for example:

```
// If the file doesn't have an IAT_DIRECTORY, we create it...
if (inh.IAT_DIRECTORY.VirtualAddress == 0) {
    inh.IAT_DIRECTORY.VirtualAddress = 123;
    inh.IAT_DIRECTORY.Size = 456;
}
```

And it works ! I don't know why. It seems that obBase and cbNew do
not make any sence too.

**Q1**: Why the IAT can be empty

**Q2**: Why MS detours must modify the IAT, what's going on

**Edit:**

An executable with empty IAT may be a packed executable. Although I still don't know the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Q1:
IAT directory can be empty because the information it contains is useless for windows loader. All needed information is in Import Table. See IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR -> FirstThunk in WinNT.h